# State managemet through session in online exam website

Tags: asp.net, session-state, state-management

I am working on an asp.net application. "Online Examination". 
my application will uses the concept of session to maintain the state of user who is giving the exam. , since in case browser shut down, system crash i do not want my user should start from the 1st question.
Infact, i want my user should start from where he left. Now i am not able to think on this.
How to test this. Is there any easy way so that i can simply test my concept.

CASE1: USER WANT TO QUIT FROM EXAM. SO HE/SHE CAN INTENTIONALLY CLOSE THE BROWSER.
CASE2: BY MISTAKE USER CLOSE THE BROWSER, SO WHEN HE RETURN BACK HE/SHE WILL START THE EXAM FROM WHERE HE/SHE LEFT.

he just have to enter the url> enter his exam id> continue the exam.

Plssss help me in this respect. give me some idea how to apply session management.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot distinguish between Case1 and Case2. Typically in these scenarios there is a button on the web page like `Logout` or `Finish` that would mark the exam as completed. Simply closing the browser would mean that the exam is still in progress.

Also note that you cannot use standard `Session` state management - that lasts only while the browser is open. You have to store the exam progress data in a database based on the user's ID.

Answer (score 0):

Use application variables so that we can easily remove this when the user suddenly closes the browser or tab.